# Possible to remove included classes?

Tags: php, kohana

I am using a 3rd party file manager plugin on a CMS and I want to include an authentication check from a PHP framework I'm using. The authentication part works fine, just a simple include then the auth check, however there then seems to be some conflict between the included classes and those of the file manager. For example, I'm getting a "Class Kohana not found" error where a class belonging to the file manager is trying to instantiate a class belonging to the framework.

At the top of my file manager main entry file, I have the following:

```
//load Kohana framework for Authorisation
include('../../../../../admin/index.php');

// If not a valid authenticated user, kill page
if ( ! Auth::instance()->logged_in())
{
    die('Unauthorized');
}
```

Having done the authentication, I no longer want the included files and classes, as these are seemingly conflicting with the file manager. Is there a way that I can do this, or am I misunderstanding what's going on here?

The error being thrown is in a file manager class - public_html/media/js/tiny_mce/plugins/ajaxfilemanager/inc/class.file.php [ 67 ]

```
function file($path=null)
{
    $this->__construct($path);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Class xyz not found` is not a sign of a conflict - it the Kohana bootstrap that probably doesn't get loaded.

There's no way to "unload" classes within a PHP script. If two packages share a class name, you'll have to load them in separate scripts, or move one of them into a separate [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) (requires PHP 5.3+). But as said, in your case, you probably just need to load the correct bootstrap file to include the needed classes.

Comment: thanks. I've tested that the bootstrap gets loaded (albeit I'm deliberately suppressing normal routing from taking place) - all that I need Kohana for actually works fine, e.g include front controller index.php then do a simple authentication check using the Auth class. I'm puzzled as to why a function in one of the file manager classes is throwing the Kohana not found error. I've added some extra info to my original post

Comment: @djonz the most common reason for that happening is when a file gets included using a `http://` path - in which case the script will run in a separate PHP instance, where the class is not loaded. Other than that, a "class not found" message in the middle of the script makes no sense if the class was successfully loaded previously

Comment: interesting re included files with http://, I'll look into that to see if that's the issue here. Thanks

Comment: finally figured out what was going on here. Turns out there's an occasional issue with eAccelerator (see http://eaccelerator.net/ticket/300). When I disable eAccelerator, the issue is gone. Ah, so much time wasted!